# Learning Resources

Tags: marketing-cloud, video

I am new to marketing cloud and will like to know where to start. I will appreciate if it anyone could point me to any video tutorials where I can learn basic programs and systems within salesforce?

Comment: You should try [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! In my experience, most the "videos" out there on marketing cloud are either advanced topics or Product Demos from salesforce. 
Here are some resources to get you started:

- [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules): For an overview on the application
- [Marketing Cloud Documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/): For deep dives across different modules. I would reccomend starting with [Email Studio](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/)
- [SprignatureMoves](https://sprignaturemoves.com/): For Advanced Topics and Best Practice
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ and search for the marketing cloud tag

After you go through these, you will be ready for these video tutorials :
Good Luck!

- Elliot Harper : [Advanced AmpScript](https://vimeo.com/219919658)
- Adam Spriggs : [AmpScript & More](https://vimeo.com/219890966)
- Girish Krishnamurthy : [Marketing Cloud Connector](https://vimeo.com/227015728)